# WCF with windows application- 2.0 .Net Framework

Tags: .net, wcf

I am new in WCF. I have to write WCF service for .Net 2.0 Windows application.
The main requirement is that I have to do this without changing any code of client. Just need to change `service url`. Is this possible?

I tried to write WCF service with `basicHttpBindings`, but it showing some extra parameters when calling method at client.

Please help..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by "shows some extra parameters"?

Comment: for example i writen method like    int Add(int a,int b) in eb service.  Then  at client when i trting to call this method it asking 6 parameters. some boolean parameters and output parameters

Comment: You said that You are not supposed to change the client code. So are You talking about some test client?

Comment: Yes..Aur all clients having application developed in .NET 2.0 framework. And they cant b able to change or upgrade there application.. I need to upgrade my current .asmx service in to WCF without changing client code.. Only need to change URL.

Comment: Please post your WCF, aspx and client code for a single method.